# Why i=i+j is not identical to i+=j

Tags: java, increment

I have below code

```
int i = 5;
long j = 5;

1. i = i + j; // Throwing an exception "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int"
2. i += j; // This working fine
```

As you can see 1st case throwing an exception but 2nd case working fine.

Why 2nd case working fine without throwing an any exception?

Comment: Second expression has an implicit type casting (to int)

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is a [`compound statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) and Compiler internally casts it. Where as in first case direct statement and compiler cries.